# can anyone explain what is going on in this program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    int m = 1;

    for (i = 0 ; i < m ; i++) {
        printf("a");
        i++;
        m++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this program is giving output as `a`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    int m = 1;

    for (i = 0 ; i < m ; i++) {
        printf("a");
        i++;
        m = 5;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

while this is giving output as `aaa`.

can anyone explain what is happening exactly.

Comment: Debug your code, that's the best explanation you can get.

Comment: In all seriousness, you should google how a for loop works.

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first program, you do `i++` twice, and `m++` once. So at the end of the first iteration, the values of i and m are equal (which is 2) - so in the next iteration `i < m` condition fails, and the loop exits.

In the second case, you set the value of m (the stop condition) to `5`, and the loop executes until the (`m<5`) stop condition is met.

Note that it is generally a bad practice to change the value of the stop condition inside the loop, as it leads to confusion such as this.

Answer (score 2):

To find errors like these it is helpful to run the program manually line by line and to observe what values the variables take.

For the first program:

```
int i;             // i = ?
int m = 1;         // i = ?, m = 1
i = 0;             // i = 0, m = 1
i < m              // true
// first iteration
printf ("a");
i++;               // i = 1, m = 1
m++;               // i = 1, m = 2
i++;               // i = 2, m = 2
i < m              // false
```

You see immediately that the problem is the extra `i++` in the body of the loop.

For the second program:

```
int i;              // i = ?
int m = 1;          // i = ?, m = 1
i = 0;              // i = 0, m = 1
i < m               // true
// first iteration
printf ("a");
i++;                // i = 1, m = 1
m = 5;              // i = 1, m = 5
i++;                // i = 2, m = 5
i < m               // true
// second iteration
printf ("a");
i++;                // i = 3, m = 5
m = 5;              // i = 3, m = 5
i++;                // i = 4, m = 5
i < m               // true
// third iteration
printf ("a");
i++;                // i = 5, m = 5
m = 5;              // i = 5, m = 5
i++;                // i = 6, m = 5
i < m               // false
```

Again you can see why there are only three iterations.

You should learn this "hand debugging" technique. It is very helpful to figure out exactly what is happening in your program. Once you have more experience you can use a debugger.